# How do you style VueJS components?

Tags: css, vue.js

Beginner with Vue - so aplogies of this is a daft question or I've missed something; but I assumed that you'd be able to target the custom element, IE:

my-element { styles go here}

However, when I've created an element, it seems I'm only able to target the elements it contains. EG - I created a nav-bar element (below), but I could only style the actual nav/img/a elements within it - like you would normally, if that makes sense?

```
Vue.component
('nav-bar', {
            template:   '<nav>'+
                        '<img src="" alt="header-logo">'+
                        '<div class="ui-component">'+
                        '<input type="text">'+
                        '<a href="#">logout</a>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '</nav>'
        });
        var nav = new Vue({
            el: '#nav'
        });
```

Am I missing something, or can you only style web elements and not custom elements in vue?

Comment: If you want true custom element support, you need to resort to libraries like Polymer.

Comment: Why not try first with your original way of styling component. Vue does offer some new ways, but old ways still work. And if old ways doesn't work, probably you should first get that to work. Because that might be a bug at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a `nav-bar` component you can simply assign a class to your custom component for styling like so:

```
<nav-bar class="my-css-selector"></nav-bar>
```

This is perfectly legit way to add a selector to your custom element.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I could use Classes/IDs, but thought once the component was registered that I could target that element like a normal html element. 

Thanks for the response`1

Comment: I assume the custom HTML tags don't end up in the rendered html though, no?

Comment: Your custom HTML attributes will show up. It is also possible to use a CSS selector to target your custom HTML element if you want. So you can use a CSS selector like this: `nav-bar { color: black; }`

Comment: @connexo - they don't render! This will be why! Thanks so much.
Stephan-v - as above, no <nav-bar></nav-bar> is rendered; assuming this is why I can't target it. 

Thanks a lot all!

Comment: That link doesn't say anything about `nav-bar { ... }` based styling. So **if at all** I'd expect this to be handled by `vue-loader`, which can ofc only work if you either import the styles in the component, or declare them directly in the vue file.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll need to assign a class/ID in the template and style it that way as not using loader ATM. 

Thank you both for your help with this.

EDIT - actually, if it's not rendering, the assigned class won't display, will it?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't recommend putting any static classes on the component tag itself. Imo that opportunity is meant to be used for dynamic classes determined at run-time.

Comment: OKay, cool. Re-tested and if I add an ID to the nav element, it'll style based on that. 

Think I need to learn about loader and style this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [single-file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#ad), you can write CSS just for the component, which they call [scoped CSS](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html). Don't confuse this with the [obsolete css scoped attribute](https://www.sitepoint.com/5-obsolete-features-html5/#3-the-scoped-attribute); it is a Vue feature.